# About joining two table with unique index

Tags: mysql

I have two table like this

table "X"

```
idX(pk) contentX(char)
10         foo1
21         foo2
34         foo3
45         foo4
```

table "Y"

```
idY(pk) contentY(char)
11         boo1
22         boo2
33         boo3
40         boo4
```

And after joining, intsert to a table and become this

```
idNew(pk)    idX(UQ) content(char)    idY(UQ) content(char)
   1           10         foo1           11         boo1
   2           21         foo2           22         boo2
   3           34         foo3           33         boo3
   4           45         foo4           40         boo4
```

The SQL I use is like this

```
    INSERT INTO DataBase.newtable(idX, contentX,idY,contentY)
        SELECT  X.idX, Y.idY, contentX, contentY
                FROM DataBase.X, DataBase.Y, ;
```

But the SQL statement cannot insert to newtable because the idX and idY is needed to be unique value. What can I do?

Comment: What are the indexes on the new table? Your example should not have any problems if each of the fields in new table are single column indexes.

Comment: the index is a new one on the new table. and if I use my sql statement, The newtable will be the result of (X x Y).

Comment: and the SQL show up "Error - 1062: Duplicate entry" error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the join field for that insert, otherwise you are going to get the Cartesian product of both tables (I.e. 16 rows). If you have unique indexes on the idx and idy fields, this constraint would cause insert to fail.

Comment: but how to sort out the unwanted row after join. That is the part I really dont know how to implement.